# Can't see a TextView in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

I've made a XML with RelativeLayout with the following code:
I can't see the TextView with the id "TV_voucher_number".
I've tried maybe making the XML a scrollview, but then I can't see the ListView properly.
The code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ManageYourTrip.mytguideapp.Voucher" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/voucherTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Voucher"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/voucherTitle"
            android:text="Date: "
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            >
        </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_voucher_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TV_Date"
        android:layout_below="@id/voucherTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12sp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_supplier_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/TV_Date"
        android:text="Supplier Details:"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_supplier_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/TV_supplier_title"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LI_TV_suppliers_Address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/TV_supplier_name"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_products_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/LI_TV_suppliers_Address"
        android:text="PRODUCTS"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_products_quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/LI_TV_suppliers_Address"
        android:text="Qty."
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ProductsList"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/TV_products_title">
    </ListView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/voucher_number"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/ProductsList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:text="VOUCHER #"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold">
        </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_voucher_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/voucher_number"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ProductsList"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:text="REF #"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The id = TV_voucher_number doesn't have text! You added text by your code?

Comment: wrap your `xml` with `ScrollView` and give a `tools:text="some text"` so you see that `TextView`, Or give a weight to `ListView` so you can maintain `scrolls` easier

Comment: Of course. The code cums from the code. Like some of the other TextViews (TV_voucher_date or TV_supplier_name for example).

Comment: When I try wraping it with a scrollview the listview isn't showing properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ManageYourTrip.mytguideapp.Voucher" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/voucherTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Voucher"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_Date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/voucherTitle"
        android:text="Date: "
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_voucher_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TV_Date"
        android:layout_below="@id/voucherTitle"
        android:textSize="12sp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_supplier_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/TV_Date"
        android:text="Supplier Details:"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_supplier_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/TV_supplier_title"
        android:textSize="12dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LI_TV_suppliers_Address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/TV_supplier_name"
        android:textSize="12dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_products_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/LI_TV_suppliers_Address"
        android:text="PRODUCTS"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_products_quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/LI_TV_suppliers_Address"
        android:text="Qty."
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ProductsList"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TV_products_title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/voucher_number"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="VOUCHER #"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold">
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TV_voucher_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="123"
                android:textSize="12dp">
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ProductsList"
        android:text="REF #"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically you just need to set your listview above bottom_layout and put your bottom_layout to be alightParentBottom. Hope this is what you want;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `ProductsList` which override the `TV_voucher_number` height. This might be the issue.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ManageYourTrip.mytguideapp.Voucher" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/voucherTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Voucher"
            android:textColor="@color/buttons_bg"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_Date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/voucherTitle"
        android:text="Date: "
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/buttons_bg"
        >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_voucher_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TV_Date"
        android:layout_below="@id/voucherTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/buttons_bg"
        android:textSize="12sp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_supplier_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/TV_Date"
        android:text="Supplier Details:"
        android:textColor="@color/buttons_bg"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_supplier_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/TV_supplier_title"
        android:textColor="@color/buttons_bg"
        android:textSize="12dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LI_TV_suppliers_Address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/TV_supplier_name"
        android:textColor="@color/buttons_bg"
        android:textSize="12dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_products_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/LI_TV_suppliers_Address"
        android:text="PRODUCTS"
        android:textColor="@color/buttons_bg"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_products_quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/LI_TV_suppliers_Address"
        android:text="Qty."
        android:textColor="@color/buttons_bg"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_ListView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/TV_products_title"
        android:weightSum="3">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ProductsList"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        >
    </ListView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/voucher_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/buttons_bg"
        android:layout_below="@id/ProductsList"
        android:text="VOUCHER #"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_voucher_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_ListView"
        android:textColor="@color/buttons_bg"
        android:text="Hello Wrord"
        android:textSize="12dp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Ref"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/TV_voucher_number"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/row_body_background_even"
        android:text="REF #"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: when I try changing the android:layout_height in PtoductList to "wrap_content" I can't see It

Comment: OOps, missed a point. Add `android:layout_below="@id/TV_voucher_number"` to the last textView and dont change productsList height

Comment: Tried it already. I've changed it to see if the "match_parent" may solve the problem

Comment: Thank's for trying but still, the number isn't showing. As if I can't see anything below the "voucher_number"

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the last 3 textview inside a relative layout, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ProductsList">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/voucher_number"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="VOUCHER #"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TV_voucher_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/voucher_number"
    android:text="HELLO"
    android:textSize="12dp">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/TV_voucher_number"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="REF #"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold">
</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes. I've put a number in it but I can't see it. There are other fields with data that comes from the app itself

Answer (score 0):

Change height of this `TextView` to wrap_content as below:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/voucher_number"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/ProductsList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" //THIS GUY
    android:text="VOUCHER #"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold">
</TextView>
```

and of course set a text to `TV_voucher_number`.

It works fine